# Justify + TabSpaces does not work on CKEDITOR

Tags: ckeditor, paragraph, justify

team!
When I use "config.tabSpaces = 20;" in justified text, he gets different spaces. for example:

first paragraph:

```
<p style="text-align:justify">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Al&eacute;m disso, constata-se que a parte reclamante recebeu, como &uacute;ltima remunera&ccedil;&atilde;o, valor <strong><u>muito acima do piso dos banc&aacute;rios, diferenciando-o de um SIMPLES CAIXA, quer seja pelas atividades desenvolvida, quer seja pela maior remunera&ccedil;&atilde;o auferida.</u></strong></p>
```

second paragraph:

```
<p style="text-align:justify">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Nesse passo, verifica-se que era depositada uma confian&ccedil;a acima do comum, al&eacute;m daquela que &eacute; inerente a qualquer rela&ccedil;&atilde;o de emprego, <strong>e muito diferenciada das responsabilidades daqueles que exercem cargos de base (caixas, agentes ou atendentes comerciais)</strong>, estes sim, banc&aacute;rios comuns.</p>
```

see that tab spaces were different, microsoft word redistributes spaces as the length of the sentence

someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CKEditor is not Microsoft Word**. CKEditor is focused on editing fragments of HTML documents from the semantical (structural) POV, not from the visual POV. You cannot expect it to work as Microsoft Word which, despite the seeming similarities, is a totally different tool.

So the behaviour you encountered is the right behaviour, because it is caused by how HTML and CSS works.

Comment: Hi, Reinmar! Thank's for reply my question.
This component is great, and easy to use..
thank's for help